# Как вернуть переменную из then()

Tags: javascript

Функция вычисляет md5 хэш для файлов изображений. Взял с инета. Но знаний моих не хватает чтоб вернуть (return) из функции get_image_filehash() переменную image_filehash.

```
function get_image_filehash () {
var input = document.getElementById('input_image_file');
if (!input.files.length) {
    return;
}

var file = input.files[0];
var bufferSize = Math.pow(1024, 2) * 10;

calculateMD5Hash(file, bufferSize).then(
    function(result) {
        var image_filehash = {
            'filehash': result.hashResult,
            'status': true
        };
        console.log(image_filehash);
    },
    function(err) {
        var image_filehash = {
            'filehash': null,
            'status': false
        };
        console.log(image_filehash);
    });
```

}

Кучу сайтов пречитал и не смог понять как это сделать. Подскажите как?

Answer (score 3):

Функция `calculateMD5Hash` асинхронная. Это значит, что она выполняется не сразу, а спустя некоторое время. Т.е. если вы вызовите функцию таким образом: `let imageFileHash = get_image_filehash();`, то на момент вызова вы не получите ожидаемого результата, поскольку он еще не получен. Вы можете создать переменную извне и присвоить ей значение, в момент выполнения колбэков.

```
let imageFileHash;

function get_image_filehash () {
  var input = document.getElementById('input_image_file');
  if (!input.files.length) {
    return;
  }

  var file = input.files[0];
  var bufferSize = Math.pow(1024, 2) * 10;

  calculateMD5Hash(file, bufferSize).then(
    function(result) {
        var image_filehash = {
            'filehash': result.hashResult,
            'status': true
        };
        console.log(image_filehash);
        imageFileHash = image_filehash;
    },
    function(err) {
        var image_filehash = {
            'filehash': null,
            'status': false
        };
        imageFileHash = image_filehash;
    });
}
```